# Two expressions in Smedley Butler's speech "You've got to get mad" from the 1930s

Tags: american-english

I have a question about two expressions used by Butler in the following speech. Here's the paragraph in which they show up to give you some context:

> We are divided, in America, into two classes: The Tories on one side, a class of citizens who were raised to believe that the whole of this country was created for their sole benefit, and on the other side, the other 99 per cent of us, the soldier class, the class from which all of you soldiers came. That class hasn’t any privileges except to die when the Tories tell them. Every war that we have ever had was gotten up by that class. They do all the beating of the drums. Away the rest of us go. When we leave, you know what happens. We march down the street with all the **Sears-Roebuck soldiers** standing on the sidewalk, all the dollar-a-year men with spurs, all the patriots who call themselves patriots, **square-legged women** in uniforms making Liberty Loan speeches.

**"Sears-Roebuck soldier"**: Is anyone in here familiar with this expression? I know that Sears-Roebuck was (is?) a mail order company from which you could order pretty much everything back in the day, but what does Butler mean when he says that someone is a "Sears-Roebuck soldier"? My impression is that it denotes some sort of fake warrior type who will not be doing the actual fighting, but who is most belligerent and gung-ho about war. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**"square-legged women"**: What about this one? Does this mean that the woman has "square-shaped" legs in the sense that they are not well-shaped and round, or is it some 1930s slang that means the opposite -- that they are well-shaped? The latter would suggest that that's why she holds Liberty Loan speeches; to put an attractive woman on stage would make more men buy Liberty Bonds.

I hope someone has the answer to these very important questions. :)

Here's the whole speech by the way if someone wants to read it:
https://semperfidelissociety.org/youve-got-get-mad-major-general-smedley-d-butler/

Comment: Could *Sears-Roebuck soldier* be a way of saying "toy soldiers"?

Comment: **Square-legged** is a term of approbation in a furniture-carpentry context. Sturdily built.  I think you could subsitute the phrase "sturdy women" there, or "matrons".

Comment: Thank you TimR, that sounds convincing to me.

Comment: Sturdy legged women wouldn't necessarily be complimentary. Since women are supposed to be slim and delicate.

Comment: Square-legged sounds like a variation on "legs like tree trunks" which is commonly used of strong but unfeminine women whose legs might be muscled and "straight up and down" rather than shapely curves. Not exactly sure if this is on-topic as it's discussing a figure of speech in a literary text, but will defer to the majority.

Comment: @Stuart F I wouldn't exactly call it a literary text. It was a speech that Butler gave to an audience of about 10 000 veterans, and he always spoke in plain everyday language, with a lot of "damns" and "hells" thrown in. :)

Comment: It is not *an expression*. It's just an **image**. Sears Roebuck is something like "down home", reliable, durable American products and brands. "On January 25, 1993, Sears ceased production of its famous Big Book catalog". There had also been a name change at some point. https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/before-folding-30-years-ago-the-sears-catalog-sold-some-surprising-products-180981504/

Comment: The phrase "You've got to get mad" hearkens back to the movie *Network* where the crazy newscaster invigorates his viewers to take action. Likely the same sentiment.

Comment: An interesting piece of history which I never heard of [US military attacks demonstrating American War Veterans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNOsIB5VMSQ&t=229s) The march took place in 1932, where 10,000 unemployed veterans protested at the US Capitol, demanding that their WWI bonus certificates be refunded by the government.

Comment: https://taskandpurpose.com/news/marine-medal-of-honor-smedley-butler-bonus-army/ (1932)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Yes, that event was firmly in the memory of the veterans when Butler gave this speech about a year later. But the main reason for the speech was that president Roosevelt had made things even worse by removing half a million veterans from the government pension rolls (the Economy Act of March 20, 1933).

Comment: How could it hurt to drop all down to and including 'When we leave, you know what happens…' What difference might that make?

Answer (score 1):

I think Sears-Roebuck was a *mail-order catalogue* retailer, so Sears-Roebuck soldiers probably implies "off-the peg" (all the same, anyone will do). It's not an expression that ever had any currency, though.

I note that the ***only*** instances of "square-**legged** women" in all the millions of tomes indexed by Google Books are this exact usage, so it hardly really "means" anything. But my guess is the speaker is getting mixed up with derogatory "square-**heads**" for Nazi (far-right, extreme "Tory") German soldiers, who wore "squarish" helmets.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I think the "off-the peg" soldier interpretation could be a proper one if Butler was referring to soldiers who will not be going overseas to fight in France. That would explain why they are standing on the sidewalk and not marching down the street with "us" who are leaving. I wonder if that is what he meant though.

Comment: I just checked. Sears-Roebuck *was* a mail-order catalogue retailer, so I think you can be 100% certain the intended sense is the draftees are just "standard issue / mass-produced cannon fodder" to be used as the ruling class see fit. In context, that presumably means they *will* be sent to die in Europe (they're cheap and readily available, so why not?).

Comment: ...but given zero currency for this guy's *square-legged women,* and the fact that we're looking at text almost a century old, I wouldn't worry too much about what *any* of it meant, even at the time. And probably most of what meaning it *did* have is no longer relevant and/or comprehensible today anyway!

Comment: The quote says that the Sears-Roebuck soldiers are watching on the sidewalk, while the soldier class marches off to war. So I'm not sure they're the "anyone will do".

Comment: @Barmar: Fair enough. I haven't bothered to read the full passage, because as I've pointed out, the usages being questioned never had any currency anyway. So it's not even worth voting to migrate to ELL, since there's nothing useful to "learn" here anyway.

Comment: ...people buy (bought) things from Sears-Roebuck on the basis of ***appearances*** (because all the buyer sees is photographs of models wearing e.g. lingerie in their catalogue; s/he can't "handle the goods"). So it may be the writer thinks those goods might not be as good *in reality* as they looked in the photographs. I don't even know (or care, frankly) whether Sears-Roebuck is/was thought of as "upmarket" or "downmarket" a century ago, but that would probably affect how his words should be understood.

Comment: BTW, Sears-Roebuck is also a department store. They were mail-order only from 1894 to 1925. The quoted story is from 1933, so it's not clear what the author was referring to.

Comment: Smedley Butler was a "soldier's general", a man who fought for the welfare of the rank and file and the overseas veterans. He would never speak disparagingly about the "expendables" who were being sent off to war. So my take on it is that a Sears-Roebuck soldier is either a soldier who is staying in the U.S. (therefore on the sidewalk) or someone who is not a soldier but acting tough and being belligerent.

Comment: And just to add: These questions are actually important to me because I'm currently translating this text into another language. I am not a native English speaker so I thought I should get some input from people who are. I thank all of you for your answers.

Comment: It is not an expression; it is just an image. At one time, everyone ordered stuff via the Sears Roebuck catalog. Things bought at SR were considered to be bona fide American products and brands and reliable. "On January 25, 1993, Sears ceased production of its famous Big Book catalog". https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/before-folding-30-years-ago-the-sears-catalog-sold-some-surprising-products-180981504/There was also a name change in there somewhere.

Comment: As a side note, you could get almost anything from Sears -- even a house! http://www.searsarchives.com/homes/1908-1914.htm

Comment: @TimR: I didn't know that. I just assumed they primarily sold *underwear* - either unavailable or that people might feel awkward about buying in person locally. If it was part of their profile that they could supply *anything and everything,* that would probably be relevant to the cited usage. But "learning English" it ain't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One of the problems with SE generally is that a question with a "no" answer often gets closed.  But I think the question "Was *square-legged* an idiom in American English during the 1930s?" is valid.

Answer (score 1):

*Square-legged women in uniforms making Liberty Loan speeches* is certainly not meant to be flattering to those women. The mind wanders to the very unflattering possibility that he regarded these women's legs as square, meaning at right angles, as opposed to the demure posture of proper women with their knees pinned together. I do hope some reasonable explanation can displace my imagination, and soon.

Comment: I believe you are absolutely on the right track. This answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If this is part of your answer then you might give me a point to go forward. Thanks